# What are some good books for learning about software design/architechure?

Tags: software-design

Not a book that talks about how to code but more high level organization of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[General Responsibility Assignment Software  Principles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062) and [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) are in my opinion are the next must have things you should get familiar with after learning to code. [API Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209739) is also a good read, especially when you are developing the software that will be used/extended by multiple people.

I am not in favor of learning patterns as it is EASIER to misuse them if the intention is not understood correctly. (Everything seems like a nail if you have a hammer kind of thing). I have nothing against patterns but I have seen it mostly misused by the junior developers thus creating hard to maintain products.

Answer (score 1):

My Professor at RWTH recommended these:

Jacobson, I., et al (1992): Object Oriented Software Engineering

Meyer, B. (1997) : Object Oriented Software Construction,2nd edition, Prentice Hall, ISBN 0-136-29155-4

Answer (score 1):

Though perhaps it is not strictly architecture-related (although I believe you'll find that most prescriptions of architecture patterns are mere *guidelines* at best, and far from comprehensive), **Steve McConnell's [*Code Complete*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) is truly required reading.** More importantly than teaching you design patterns, it will teach you to be a better programmer so that you can make these kinds of decisions for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Fowler's *Design Patterns*. Deep stuff, some of it's hard to get through, but yum.