# Where to after a year of java?

Tags: java, computer-science

I've just finished a my first year of programming Java at varsity and I have a three month break.

In terms of my development would it be better to:

- Cover Java in more depth to acquire a more intermediate level of ability
- Learn a new programming language (if so which) to a similar level as my current Java ability
- Spend timing learning introductory discrete maths, algorithms and data structures

I'm also open to any other possibilities that would be beneficial but that could be covered in about 3 months

Comment: Belongs to: programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write code. Having written actual code is much more valuable than reading books. It seems it's a problem that programmers can't write code - [see here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html). So in order not to be one of those that can't program, write code.

You can undertake a project of your taste. Since it's now popular, you can create some social tool, like TweetDeck or HootSuite. Or you can create an arbitrary useful software. For the cornet-shop or car-repair garage of a relative of yours, whatever.

Comment: I think you should have linked to [the DailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) instead of Coding Horror. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my response to a similar kind of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289835/what-are-some-good-books-for-learning-about-software-design-architechure/4290076#4290076)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a subjective question... but I would suggest learning popular design patterns. Also find a project for yourself, find something that interests you, or a problem you want to solve. Spend your free time solving that problem or creating something interesting. The best way to learn is application in real world settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the:

- Spend timing learning introductory discrete maths, algorithms and data structures

It will give you a solid base for whatever you want to do next, other languages or as Pangea suggest above (DDD, UML etc.)

Edit: and yeah as another points out: write code, and lots of it.

Comment: I would upvote you if it wasnt for the yelling.

Comment: Hehe sorry for that, copy/pasted the bullet from the question, but it came out as yelling.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put what you have learned into practice. Create a project for yourself.

Alternatively, you can learn about [Enterprise Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html) and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Write code is probably the best answer.

However the timespan you have to work with begs a mention of *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks*.
http://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks

Answer (score 0):

as a student, id faced a similar dilemma a year back.. i opted to learn c++, and its been a good decision. c++ gives you an insight into pointers and you learn about garbage collection (which java normally does automatically), etc.. plus its not hard to learn c++ with a java background..
or you could embark on a project (perhaps learn JSP, servlets, beans for an e-commerce website), which is another excellent option..

Answer (score 0):

You should start learning Java EE.

JSP, Servelets, Tomcat is a good start. Spring maybe after.

Remember to write code more than you read. Try editing ready examples.